# Django template tags all() and count() don't work what should I do

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am very new to Django so bare with me.

I have a model called Posts that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=127)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.author} : {self.content} -- ({self.date})"
```

And a model of Likes that looks like this:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='likes')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= CASCADE, related_name='liked')
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'user')
```

From the Like model I have a foreign key that points to my Post model.
If I want to access the amount of likes a post has I write this in the shell:

```
post1 = Post.objects.get(id =1)
post1.likes.all().count()
```

This is my view for rendering posts

```
@require_GET
def getposts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-date').all()
    p = Paginator(posts, 10)
    someposts = p.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))

    rendered_posts = render_to_string('network/posts.html', context={'page':someposts})
    
    return JsonResponse({'posts': rendered_posts})
```

This is how post.html looks like

```
{% for post in page.object_list%}
<div class="post">
    <ul class="post__head">
        <li class="author">{{post.author.username}}</li>
        <li class="date">{{post.date}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">{{post.content}}</p>
    <div class="post__actions">
        <span class="like__button"></span>
        <p class="like__amount">{{post.likes.all().count()}}</p>   
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Now this line is what's giving me trouble:**

```
<p class="like__amount">{{post.likes.all().count()}}</p>
```

I get an error that **I can't use all() and count() in my template**

I was wondering if there's a way of making a function that returns the like count when i call it.
Something in models.py like:

```
def getLikes():
   return post.likes.all().count()
```

and if I call post1.getLikes() it returns the number of likes in post1?

Thank you and Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's template engine is *deliberately* restricted to prevent people from writing *business logic* in a template: a template should contain *rendering logic*. Usually it is better to do this through the views.

We can make a queryset that contains the `like_count` with:

```
@require_GET
def getposts(request):
    #         add annotation ↓
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(
        like_count=Count('likes')
    ).order_by('-date')
    
    p = Paginator(posts, 10)
    someposts = p.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))

    rendered_posts = render_to_string('network/posts.html', context={'page':someposts})
    return JsonResponse({'posts': rendered_posts})
```

The advantage of annotating, is that this means that the number of likes are determined in the same query where we load the `Post` objects, so it will slightly slow down that query, but it will only make *one* query, whereas using `post.likes.count()` will make an extra query *per* `Post` item.

Then we can render this as:

```
<p class="like__amount">{{ post.like_count }}</p>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. So do you think using annotate is more efficient than the answer from @allexiusw ?

Comment: @PaulaUzcategui: making a query *per* item, is known as the infamous [*N+1 problem*](https://scoutapm.com/blog/django-and-the-n1-queries-problem). It means that if you want to render 100 posts, it will make 101 queries, whereas this can be simplified to a single query that perhaps takes three times more time than a simple query, but that is then one query.

Comment: Yes, @PaulaUzcategui you are right, annotate is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @WillemVanOnsem to the infamoust N+1 problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are about to achieve the goal:
When you work in templates you don't have to use `()` just call methods from templates like this:

```
{{post.likes.all.count}}
```

But if you want to abstract the logic to the model that 'is better' you can do the following:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=127)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.author} : {self.content} -- ({self.date})"
    
    def getLikes(self):
        return self.likes.all().count()
```

Then you can call it in your template:

```
{{post.getLikes}}
```

That's it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!